# Calculating percentile counts in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large array ex 
`[1,4,5,9,1,4,6,....]`

I wanna calculate how many elements in total fall below each percentile.
Ex:

````
4 numbers in 10percentile
7 numbers in 20 percentile
10 numbers in 30 percentile and so on till 100. ```

Is there a simple way to do this
````

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html#numpy-percentile

Comment: @PedroLobito It gives the value but not the count of values which fall in a percentile.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely do it with `np.percentile` but need to write a little bit of your own code too. Here I am using a dictionary to do it. The last for loop is not very necessary but I am doing just because of the demonstration purpose.

```
arr=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,1,5,3,6,2,6,3,5,2,6,8,6,78,97,77,45])

percentile=np.percentile(arr,np.arange(10,110,10))

dic={}
for i,j in zip(percentile,np.arange(10,110,10)):
    dic[j]=np.sum(arr<=i)

for key,value in dic.items():
    print(str(value)+' numbers in '+str(key)+' percentile')
```

Result:

```
5 numbers in 10 percentile
5 numbers in 20 percentile
8 numbers in 30 percentile
9 numbers in 40 percentile
12 numbers in 50 percentile
17 numbers in 60 percentile
17 numbers in 70 percentile
17 numbers in 80 percentile
19 numbers in 90 percentile
22 numbers in 100 percentile
```